# What is the benefit of multiple people working in a store?

Tags: tiny-tower

In the game Tiny Tower, you can assign up 3 people to work in a store. What are the benefits of having a store fully staffed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fully staffed stores allow you to fully stock stores. Each additional stock increases in value and quantity available.  This allows you to keep a store open longer, sell more stuff, and make more money.

Additionally, staffing stores with 3 dream jobs will give you the x2 stock per slot.

Outside of Food Floors, which typically carry low stock and generate low profits, every other type of floor should have 3 workers to maximize profits.

Comment: Additionally, you have a chance to receive 1 Bit Buck for fully stocking a floor. This can only be done by having 3 workers.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is kinda late, but depending on the number on the bitizen for the floor type you employ them in, will make each item cheaper by that number as a percent.  This number is added to the others for the bitizens employed there.  That added percentage is universal to each 3 items on that floor.

Answer (score 2):

Having more people work at stores allows you to get more items for the store.

Answer (score 1):

Once a store is fully stocked, there is no benefit to keeping the Bitizens there.  Keep the floor fully-staffed until it is fully-stocked, then you are free to shuffle the Bitizens around as you please with no penalty while the supply runs down.  I do this when I have more job openings than Bitizens.

In general though, it's best to leave the Bitizens with their dream job at their dream job, or else you may forget about the matchup.